# Запись в txt файл через SFTP протокол

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер!

Как записать текст(с новой строчки) в файл `proverka.txt`, используя протокол SFTP?

Пример:

```
Текст 1
Текст 2
```

Через функцию `AppendAllText` текст записывается, но не получается перенос строки сделать. Пробовал `\r\n`, но так получается, что каждое введенное слово после запятой переносится.

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ip, port, user, password))
    {
        try
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    sftp.AppendAllText("/dir1/dir2/proverka.txt", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + ",");
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
        }
        finally
        {
            sftp.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: код, где код???

Comment: Сорри, забыл =)
Добавил в первый пост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем же тратить время соединения, если текст для записи можно сформировать заранее и без оглядки на методы, предоставляемые классом `SftpClient`?

```
private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            text.Append(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString());
            if (j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
            {
                // добавляем запятую для всех значений кроме последнего
                text.Append(",");
            }
        }
        // добавляем перенос строки после того, как обработали ряд
        text.AppendLine();
    }

    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ip, port, user, password))
    {
        try
        {
            sftp.Connect();
            sftp.AppendAllText("/dir1/dir2/proverka.txt", text.ToString());
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка");
        }
        finally
        {
            sftp.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде работает. Но, появился какой-то косяк..
Добавляю первую строку - добавляет, добавляю вторую - добавляет и первую и вторую и так далее..

А можно, как-то переделать код чтобы он перезаписывал весь файл, а содержимое брал из dataGridView? Таким образом, получится что он будет брать даже изменения. Я делал подобное (запись/чтение), но не SFTP, а тут что-то не получается.

Comment: @Максим вы имеете в виду, что хотите, чтобы при каждом нажатии на кнопку файл **перезаписывался**? Тогда либо ищите в классе `SftpClient` метод, который позволит перезаписать файл, либо удаляйте его перед вызовом `AppendAllText`.

Comment: Спасибо! Я поторопился с комментарием и уже сам заменил функцию на AppendAllText. Большое вам спасибо!!! =) Работает!

Comment: @Максим не за что!

Comment: @Максим кстати, какую библиотеку вы используете для SFTP?

Comment: Renci.SshNet (15 сим)